# Passing a list of randomForest objects back to R with rpy2

Tags: python, r, random-forest, rpy2

I am trying to combine a number of random forest models using rpy2. The `combine` command in R looks fairly straight forward but I am not sure how to pass the RF objects from python to R.

Simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from string import lowercase
else:
    from string import ascii_lowercase as lowercase
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
r = robjects.r

r.library("randomForest")

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random(size=(100, 10)), columns=[a for a in lowercase[:10]])
cols = df.columns
RF = []

for _ in range(5):
    df['train'] = np.random.random(size=100) < .75
    rf = r.randomForest(robjects.Formula('a~.'), data=df[df.train][cols])
    RF.append(rf)
```

When I try and `combine` RF models in R

```
RFall = r.combine(RF)
```

Returns the error:

```
Error in (function (...)  : 
  Argument must be a list of randomForest objects
```

I have looked at other functions in `robjects` but can't find the one that will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is originating from R, there the list expected is an R list.

Try using:

```
RFl = robjects.vectors.ListVector([('X%i' % i, x) for i, x in enumerate(RF)])
```

**edit:** the constructor for ListVector wants names for the list elements

** 2nd edit:** However, the real path to a solution is to notice that you were not calling `combine()` correctly and the error message returned when calling `combine()` is quite misleading. What you want(ed) is

```
RFall = r.combine(*RF)
```

Comment: Sorry @Igautier, I thought this was working. But I have just tried it again and am getting a `ValueError: too many values to unpack` error

Comment: I may miss something, but it should work. Can you make sure the code example in the question can be reproduced ?

Comment: @Igautier code example reproduces error, I have tried it on a couple of different Python installs

Comment: @kungphil : what I mean is that the example should preferably work with copy/paste (here `lowercase` does not seem to be found... until one realizes that Python 2 might have had it in `string`)

Comment: @kungphil : there was a slight problem with the way I was calling `ListVector()`. The answer has been edited.

Comment: @Igautier this works in so much as it doesn't throw an error when creating the list. But when passing this to `combine` I get this error `Error in (function (...)  : Argument must be a list of randomForest objects`. New question?